# Meteor TypeError: require(...).addStyles is not a function

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to add styles like this:

```
import './landing.css';
```

or

```
import { someClass } from "./landing.css";
```

at react component and getting this error:

> TypeError: require(...).addStyles is not a function

I am using last Meteor 1.5.2.1

/imports/ui/pages/Landing.jsx
In React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './landing.css'
// import { someClass } from "./landing.css";

export default class Landing extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid fluid id="landing">
          <Row className="show-grid">
              <Col xs={12} md={12}>
                  <h1 className="someClass">
                      Landing Page
                  </h1>
              </Col>
          </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

/imports/ui/pages/landing.css
In ./landing.css:

```
.someClass {
    color: red
}
```

Do I need some additional packages?

Comment: Show the whole code (with file paths) you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you "/imports/ui/pages/Landing.jsx" is not being imported into the "lib" or "both" or "server"?  I only see that error happen when I try to do SSR and the file is being loaded into the "lib" directory (accessible by the server and client).